# What is the best practice to input a number if it is important to have an int when it's possible?

Tags: java

I want to input a number and have it be an `int` when possible. How can I input value to int when it isn't a float/double (5 --> int, 5.0 --> double)?

I think that using regular expressions for parsing an input isn't a good idea.

Should i use a Number abstract class and instanceof operator instead?

Comment: Can you give us an example? You could always cast it to an int.

Comment: But then i could loose my float part

Comment: What does this mean then *"So how can I input value to int when it isn't a float/double"* ??

Comment: Like if enters int store as int, and if enters float sote as float ? Why don't you just store as float everytime

Comment: because it's principle to store values like 5, 10, 666 as int type

Comment: This question is pretty confusing, are you saying that you want to store the variable as the smallest type that can store it accurately? What is the reason for this? If we understand the intent we can provide better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you try to find out the input is an integer or double.

If you use a `try-catch` block, you can check the input's format.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = s.nextLine();

try {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(input);
    System.out.println("It is integer.");

} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    try {

        Double d = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println("It is double.");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {

        System.out.println(input + " is neither an integer or a double");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your situation i think it is a good practice. So if you find the answer helpful, please upvote and accept thus it can help other people that may have similar problems.